# Android GCM-server in a Struts 2 action

Tags: java, android, json, struts2, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a message to an Android device via GCM. Following the [google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app) I've added the `gcm-server.jar` library to my Struts2 project. But I'm getting an exception, my code:

```
public String execute() throws IOException {
        List<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();
        devices.add(gcmRegId);
        Sender sender = new Sender(PROJECT_API);
        Message gcmMessage = new Message.Builder().build();
        Result result = sender.send(gcmMessage, gcmRegId, 5);
}
```

The exception I'm getting is, it raises just after the creation of the `Sender` object.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
```

Am I missing something? Like a dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing library `json-simple-1.1.jar`. If you use maven then the artifact is `json-simple`, version is `1.1`, and name is `JSON.simple`. [Downloadable](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar) from the repository.

Comment: Which tutorial project are you mentioned?

Comment: I've added the link of the tutorial in my question, anyway this one [gcm gettin started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html#server-app)